# Scala Play 2.1.0 - Assets not appearing on Heroku?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework

My app works fine in development (images show), but when deploying to Heroku they mysteriously disappear.

The code is

```
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/myImage.png")"" />
```

Is Heroku messing this up or am I missing something?

Comment: How does it look in the page's source in the browser ???

Comment: It comes out as 
    <img src="/assets/images/myImage.png" />
with a broken image icon.

Comment: Don't you have too many quotation marks in that img tag? Two opening marks but three closing marks. I'm not saying that's the real problem but it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your project's `public` directory is in your git repo.

Comment: This did it, I was apparently forgetting to 'git add -A'

Comment: I have the same problem and my public directory is added, as it can find the css files and images. But the fonts I try to use via @font-face cannot be loaded. Any hints?

Comment: Hmm, the font name in the css are case sensitive. Strange that on my Mac this didn't matter and on the Heroku server it did.

Comment: You file system on your Mac is probably not case sensitive but Linux is always case sensitive.

Comment: One more comment.  I would also check your .gitignore.  the default one generated by play had dist/ listed which screwed up with my bower installed artifacts.  Thanks for the fix though. :)