# Play!Framework + Heroku: cannot find assets

Tags: git, heroku, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to deploy my Play!Framework to Heroku but I'm having the following errors:

```
app[web.1]: [error] application - Error reading filename: create_user.json
app[web.1]: [error] application - Error reading filename: delete_user.json
app[web.1]: [error] application - Error reading filename: login_user.json
...
```

I use these .json file as schema to validate the inputs from the client. They are located under the 'app/assets/json/' directory.
I guess they aren't being pushed to Heroku at all, but I don't know how to check that either.

I saw similar issues where the missing files are located under 'public' directory, so that a 'git add -A' would solve the problem:

[Scala Play 2.1.0 - Assets not appearing on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835108/scala-play-2-1-0-assets-not-appearing-on-heroku)

However, it does not apply to my problem.

Additional info: Play 2.2.2, MongoHQ, server-side only.

Thank in advance!

**Edit:**

The stacktrace shows me that the application is looking for the json files at

```
/app/target/universal/stage/app/assets/json/
```

where **/app** corresponds to the default root of the application in the Heroku dyno (checked with 'heroku run bash'), **/target/universal/stage** is defined in my Procfile, and the remaining path **/app/assets/json** is the correct hierarchy in my development environment. The path above doesn't exist on Heroku, obviously.

I'm using the following method to get the json files:

```
Play.application().getFile("app/assets/json/create_user.json");
```

Works in development environment, but not in production. I don't know how to make these files accessible in production as well.

Comment: Everything that's commited to git repo is pushed also to Heroku, check if you added the json files (and commted them) with git client.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the problem. I've checked with git client and the files have been added and pushed. I did the same step to Github instead of Heroku, so I can see the files in the repo. Just started to investigate it again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Play! does not allow such operation in production mode

```
Play.application().getFile("app/assets/json/create_user.json");
```

According to James Roper, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089412/reading-from-a-file-in-play-on-heroku?rq=1), *"It's bad practice in Play to rely on the filesystem"*.

Instead, one should provide the file in either 'conf' of 'public' folders and load them as resources. These files are embedded in the packaged application.

Since his solution is in Scala, and I have found some solutions with the old Play!Framework 1.X, I decided to post what actually worked for me with Play! 2.2.2 and Java 1.7:

```
Play.application().classloader().getResourceAsStream("json/create_user.json");
```

with my .json files located at 'conf/json'.

Comment: Hello i'have same problem, I added a folder that contains indexes under the root directory during the deployment on heroku I get the following error: '/ app / target / universal / stage / index' does not exist 
I open the file from a java class. play.Play.application.getFile ("index");